# WKWebView does not use client certificates trusted by Safari

Tags: ios, certificate, wkwebview, client-certificates

We have an enterprise app which contains a `WKWebView` which needs to access a site which requires a client side certificate.

The required client certificate is installed on the device and we are able to access the protected site in Safari. Currently the client certificate is manually downloaded and trusted.

However when we try and access the same site within a `WKWebView` within our app, the site returns an HTTP 400, because it cannot find the client side certificate.

I have tried the following implementation of the appropriate `navigationDelegate` method:

```
        print("authentication challenge: \(challenge)")

        guard let trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust else {
            print("no server trust: \(challenge.protectionSpace)")
            completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, nil)
            return
        }

        print("using server trust: \(challenge.protectionSpace)")
        let cred = URLCredential(trust: trust)
        completionHandler(.useCredential, cred)
    }
```

When this method gets called for the client certificate, there is no `challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust`.

If I put the client certificate into the app bundle (generally not advised and not a viable option for production use), load it and tell WKWebView to use that credential in the `completionHandler()` callback, then the site loads.

It is my understanding that `WKWebView` should have access to the same client side certificates as Safari, hence I am at a loss to explain why this does not work.

Does anyone know of a way to get `WKWebView` to use system-wide client side certificates?

Comment: I'm also looking for a firm answer on this? As far I know, the client certificate installed on device is not accessible by anyone except Safari app or SFSafariViewController. Is there a way we can leverage SFSVC in some way?

Comment: I filed a DTS incident with Apple and they said it simply is not possible.